# Generate an APK without mapping.txt

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, proguard, obfuscation

I want to generate an APK with only one class obfuscated, that contains a time-bomb for a demo application. I've seen that exists a ProGuard integrated into Android Studio, but the code is easily reversable with *mapping.txt*.

The question is: it's a good idea to generate apk and, at the same time, removing the *mapping.txt* from it? Just to avoid deobfuscation.

Comment: mapping.txt is not included in your APK. So who are you thinking will have access to that file to reverse the code?

Comment: Your Apk is not depend on mapping.txt or run-time doesn't need mapping.txt. it's just used for debugging

Comment: Are you able to extract the mapping.txt from only the APK?  If so, what is causing the mapping.txt to be added to the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not shipping the mapping file is the right solution. It's almost always **not** a good idea to ship your mapping file to the users.